# Type mismatch error when using SignInController in Flutter Google sign-in implementation

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin

I'm currently following a Flutter tutorial on Udemy and trying to implement Google sign-in functionality in my Flutter app. However, I'm encountering a type mismatch error related to the SignInController class. Here are the details of the issue:

Problem:
I'm implementing Google sign-in in my Flutter app based on a tutorial. When trying to use the SignInController class, I'm getting the following type mismatch error:

```
The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type 'SignInController' is not a subtype of type 'SignInController' in type cast where
  SignInController is from package:udemy_chat_app/pages/sign_in//controller.dart
  SignInController is from package:udemy_chat_app/pages/sign_in/controller.dart
```

Stack Trace:

```
#0      GetInstance._startController (package:get/get_instance/src/get_instance.dart:251:44)
#1      GetInstance._initDependencies (package:get/get_instance/src/get_instance.dart:204:11)
#2      GetInstance.find (package:get/get_instance/src/get_instance.dart:301:17)
#3      GetView.controller (package:get/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_view.dart:38:37)
#4      SignInPage.build.buildThirdPartyLogin.<anonymous closure> (package:udemy_chat_app/pages/sign_in/view.dart:88:33)
#5      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1154:21)
#6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:275:24)
#7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:654:11)
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:311:5)
#9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:244:7)
#10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:630:9)
#11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98:12)
#12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:143:9)
#13     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:625:13)
#14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:141:18)
#15     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:127:7)
#16     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:465:19)
#17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:445:22)
#18     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:331:11)
#19     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:400:7)
#20     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:363:5)
#21     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:320:7)
#22     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:293:9)
#23     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:158:13)
#24     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:382:7)
#25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:91:31)
```

code:

Controller:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:udemy_chat_app/common/entities/entities.dart';
import 'package:udemy_chat_app/common/routes/names.dart';
import 'package:udemy_chat_app/common/store/store.dart';
import 'index.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes:<String>[
    'openid'
  ]
);

class SignInController extends GetxController{
  final state = SignInState();
  SignInController();
   final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
   Future<void> handleSignIn() async {
     try{
       var user = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
       if (user!=null){
         String displayName = user.displayName??user.email;
         String email = user.email;
         String id = user.id;
         String photoUrl = user.photoUrl??"";
         UserLoginResponseEntity userProfile = UserLoginResponseEntity();
         userProfile.email=email;
         userProfile.accessToken = id;
         userProfile.displayName = displayName;
         userProfile.photoUrl = photoUrl;

         UserStore.to.saveProfile(userProfile);
       }
     }catch(e){

     }
   }
}
```

view page:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:udemy_chat_app/common/values/colors.dart';
import 'package:udemy_chat_app/common/widgets/button.dart';
import 'package:udemy_chat_app/pages/sign_in/controller.dart';


class SignInPage extends GetView<SignInController> {
  const SignInPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget buildLogo(){
      return Container(
        width: 110.w,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 84.h),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 76.w,
              height: 76.w,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.w),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 76.w,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: null,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35))
                        ),
                      )
                  ),
                  Positioned(child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/ic_launcher.png',
                    width: 76.w,
                    height: 76.w,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 15.h , bottom: 15.h
              ),
              child:
              const Text(
                "Let's begin",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: AppColors.thirdElement,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  height: 1
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    Widget buildThirdPartyLogin(){
      return Container(
        width: 295.w,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 280.h,),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              'Sign in with your Social media accounts',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: AppColors.primaryText,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 30, left: 50, right: 50
            ),
              child: btnFlatButtonWidget(
                  onPressed: (){controller.handleSignIn();},
                width: 200.w,
                height: 55.h,
                title: "Sign In with Google"
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    return  Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            buildLogo(),
            Spacer(),
            buildThirdPartyLogin()
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Solution Attempted:
I have already tried the following steps to resolve the issue, but the error persists:

1-Checked the import statements to ensure the correct SignInController class is imported.

2-Cleaned the project using **flutter** clean and rebuilt it.

3-Verified that the Firebase setup is correct and all necessary dependencies are installed.

4-Double-check that I have added the necessary Firebase configuration files (e.g., google-services.json for Android or GoogleService-Info.plist for iOS).

Comment: would it be possible to create a gist for this? would be easy for any one to hop on and help that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the SHA 1 and SHA 256 to firebase to fix it.